# MySQL trigger two iterations, two cursors?

Tags: mysql, loops, triggers, cursor

I'm trying to make a trigger which iterates through two separate rows set. I want to make some kind of notification for 'friends' and I need to iterate when user is either one or the second side of the relation (profile_id or friend_profile_id).

Here's what I tried so far:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE frid INT;
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT friends.friend_profile_id FROM friends WHERE profile_id = NEW.profile_id;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

OPEN cur;
  read_loop: LOOP
    IF done THEN
        LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    FETCH cur INTO frid;

    INSERT INTO notification VALUES (NULL,NEW.profile_id,frid,NOW(),"001",0,NEW.thread_id);

  END LOOP read_loop;

CLOSE cur;
END
```

It works well (but somehow it does INSERT two times for the last row (?)).

Anyway I need to make second cursor for the second side:

`DECLARE cur2 CURSOR FOR SELECT friends.profile_id FROM friends WHERE friend_profile_id = NEW.profile_id;`

So after last `CLOSE cur;` I added the second `OPEN cur2;` and tried to do second iteration for this cursor using new variables. Unfortunately it doesn't work - only first loop works and the second part for `cur2` is ignored.

Can you suggest how to do this?

Comment: Oh I did this! Just needed to `SET done=0;` before opening the second cursor!

But still: why does it make INSERT two times at last row?

Comment: Ok, I did something far more better by using UNION on SELECT statements. Now I have only one cursor with one loop.